# Overlay a div on top of a input element

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains all these elements:

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="click"></div>
</div>
```

I want to style this in a way so that the `div` with `id=click` will be in the right corner of the input element.

The CSS I applied to text is:

```
text-align: left;
width: 400px;
```

In my `click` div I have:

```
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
```

Essentially it would look like this:

```
[____INPUT___________________{DIV}]
```

I am not sure how to style the div in order to position it over the input element. Right now it is lying directly to the right of it.

Comment: Can u make a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: You can use `input-group` of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* gives padding and border from inside */
}
#container {
  position: relative; /* for absolute child element */
  display: inline-block; /* to take the width of the input */
}
input {
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px; /* added to match the height of the #click div */
  outline: 0; /* to remove outline when focused */
}
#click {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute; /* to align it to right and positon it over the input */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="click"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for. Now what if i wanted to center `container` in the middle of the page. I've tried to do` margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` but its not working

Comment: is there any parent for `#container` ?

Comment: then add `text-align:center` to it or just add fixed `width` ie `300px` to the `#container` and set it to `margin:0 auto`

Answer (score 8):

You can use `position:absolute` for the `div#click` to control it but make sure the `#container` has `position:relative`

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j39c0p4s/1/)

```css
#container{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  outline:2px solid #060;
}
#container #click{
  width:40px;
  line-height:36px;
  background-color:#090;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
#container input[type="text"]{
  width:298px;
  height:30px;
  padding:right:40px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="click">GO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for. Now what if i wanted to center `container` in the middle of the page. I've tried to do `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` but its not working

Comment: add this to the `#container{margin:0 auto;}` check this https://jsfiddle.net/j39c0p4s/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try the below styling.

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" style="float: left;" />
  <div id="click" style="float: left; position: relative; left: -30px;"></div>
</div>
```

If your dive goes under the textbox, try applying `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:right` to `click` div.

Comment: yes but that floats it outside of the input, I want the div inside the input element

Comment: input[type="text"]{float:left;}
.click{float:left;margin-left:5px;}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS when you click on div

```
float : right;
margin-left : (as many pixel you want)px;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
 display:inline
```

property on `DIV#click` element. like i did in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wsb9fkL/)